# Understanding a Chromosomal formula in a karytope analysis

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, chromosome, medicine, karyotype

I am reading a medical reporting results of a karyotype analysis. On it it is written:

> **Chromosomal formula**
>
> 46,XX,del(7)(q11q36)[12]/46,XX[13]

I understand that `46` is the number of chromosomes, `XX` refers to the pair of sexual chromosomes, `del(7)(q11q36)` means a deletion on the long arm of chromosome 7 spanning the bands 11 to 36.

**What do `[12]` and `[13]` mean?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cytogenetic nomenclature is standardized in the [International System for Human Cytogenetic Nomenclature](https://www.karger.com/Book/Home/271658). Unfortunately it is not free and my institution does not have access. However, looking at a [preview of the 2013 version in Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lGCLrh0DIwEC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=cytogenetic+nomenclature+square+brackets&source=bl&ots=igLZNz_5ZI&sig=f_4irh4L9vbzHaFHc1ekxaX33V8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAo-r606HTAhVHyGMKHZ6DAKcQ6AEIIzAC#v=onepage&q=cytogenetic%20nomenclature%20square%20brackets&f=false), it would seem that **the number in square brackets is the number of cells scored with that karyotype**.