# How can I list genes present on a given series of bands?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, human-genetics, medicine, biotechnology

My question is related to [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58340/understanding-a-chromosomal-formula-in-a-karytope-analysis). My interest relate to this deletion:

> del(7)(q11q36)[12]

as defined by [ISCN](https://www.karger.com/Book/Home/271658).

I would like to access a list of the genes found on the bands 11 to 36 of the 7th chromosome in humans. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

There's a brief tutorial [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/howto/obtain-genomic-sequence/) on how to search by band. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/mapview/static/MapViewerHelp.html) is a more extensive help document, and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/mapview/static/humansearch.html) is a human-specific help page, Basically:

1. Select the species and annotation release. We're *Homo sapiens*, by the way...
2. Select the chromosome you are interested in.
3. On the left side of the page, it says `Region Shown:` followed by two input boxes. You can search by band using standard cytogenetic nomenclature: `7q11` and `7q36`. Enter these into the input fields and click `Go`. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/mapview/maps.cgi?TAXID=9606&CHR=7&MAPS=ideogr%2Ccntg-r%2Cregions%2Cgenes&BEG=7q11&END=7q36&oview=default) is 7q11:7q36.
4. There are various links to download data. Perhaps most relevant to you, there is a link on the left of the page which says `Data As Table View`. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/mapview/maps.cgi?TAXID=9606&CHR=7&MAPS=ideogr,cntg-r,regions,genes[60100000.00%3A159345973.00]&CMD=TXT) is said page, a list of genes at various levels of characterization.

---

[image]

[Here](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/query.html) is a table of different search queries you can use. There are a couple of ways to analyze the data:

Interactive Genome Browser:

1. Click on `Genome Browser`.
2. In the search field, enter the cytogenetic coordinates: `7q11;7q36`. Press `Go`. [Here](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr7%3A60100001%2D159345973&hgsid=588323279_uLjlQimUE7JnjyCk63plUGnVLfdK) is the resulting page.

Table Browser (for downloading data):

1. Click on `Tools > Table Browser`.
2. There are a lot of options. A tutorial can be found [here](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/hgTablesHelp.html). Most important for your search is `region`. Select the `position` radio button and enter your cytogenetic coordinates. I'll leave the rest of the options to you.

Comment: Nice answer! I like you offered directly the small tutorial and not only links to explainations. I also like you used the slogan for each data collection. Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b You're welcome, hope you find what you're after.