# Are there any online resources for visualising on which band of a chromosome a particular gene is located?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

I am studying some genes that are expressed in the brain. I use the online database UniProt to get information about the proteins encoded by the genes of interest. However, I would like to know on which chromosome and which band of the chromosome the genes are located.

I was wondering whether there are any online tools that I can use where I can type the name of a gene of interest and I can get a visualisation of which chromosome the gene is located as well as the band? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Well, given the protein, you can use http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/ then just above the sequence it mentions the chromosome and band e.g 4q31. But no visualisation here. I did see a visualisation tool for human proteins 8 years ago but I forget where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UCSC genome browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgGateway) is good for genome visualization. [Searching for HBB](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr11%3A5226620%2D5229395&hgsid=1167325625_xWceDvo9dkpbyTFQfHafMNFOe0YB), for example, gives the follow data by default:

[image]

You can also [search by band and get a list of genes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58342/how-can-i-list-genes-present-on-a-given-series-of-bands/58344#58344).